# How can I make a transparent 3D Rectangle?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

Sorry, I didn't mentioned clearly in my earlier post.

I want to build a transparent `Rectangle`, within which I want to diffuse a certain color of my choice which is also transparent. After this, any objects that I place inside the transparent building should be visible in its assigned color. One of the things that I tried to do after making a rectangle shape with light colored walls was to place `Points` with `ImageSize-> {20, 20}` and different colors. For that purpose I wrote the following code.

```
w = 100;
l = 200;
h = 30;
f = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {0, 0, h}}]},
      Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
b = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{0, l, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}}]},
      Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
s1 = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}, {0, l, h}, {0, l, 0}}]}, 
       Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
s2 = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {w, l, 0}}]}, 
       Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
sur = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {0, l, 0}}]}, 
         Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
top = Graphics3D[{Transparent,Polygon[{{0, 0, h}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}}]},
        Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False];
Show[{f, b, s1, s2, sur, top}]
```

I tried to set `Lighting` options for the 3D objects. However that does not seem to work.  Can anyone help me?

One another option that I was thinking of was to have something similar to a heat map.

Comment: Do you mean rectangle or cuboid?

Comment: Actually,I want to build a building,but that code was big,so for sampling `Rectangle` was fine...

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps easier:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Cuboid[{0,0,0}, {100,200,30}]}, Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In his case:

`Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {w, l, h}]}, 
 Lighting -> {LightBlue}, Boxed -> False]`

Comment: @Öskå Feel free to edit the answer. I just stole the example from the help, of course

Comment: @Öskå see this http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32/193

Comment: "Thank you for this answer, but it doesn't answer my question because in my application I want the bottom to be transparent, top to have the full lena picture and the sides to start from transparent at the bottom and end opaque at the top with toad watermarks in the center." Waaaaah :'(

Comment: @rm-rf And cheddar cheese as topping

Comment: No, I chose Lena as the topping

Comment: @belisarius thanks! It works :)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Opacity.html)

```
w=100;
l=200;
h=30;
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8],
 Polygon[{
  {{0,0,0},{w,0,0},{w,0,h},{0,0,h}},
  {{0,l,0},{w,l,0},{w,l,h},{0,l,h}},
  {{0,0,0},{0,0,h},{0,l,h},{0,l,0}},
  {{w,0,0},{w,0,h},{w,l,h},{w,l,0}},
  {{0,0,0},{w,0,0},{w,l,0},{0,l,0}},
  {{0,0,h},{w,0,h},{w,l,h},{0,l,h}}
 }]},
 Lighting->{LightBlue},Boxed->False]
```

[image: box]

And searching `Transparent` in the documentation you will find [Add Transparency To Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/AddTransparencyToPlots.html)