# How can I fill a wire-frame structure with gas in a Graphics3D drawing?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I am very poor at visualization. I want to make a transparent "building" filled with gas. I wrote the following code for the building and it's fine.

```
 w = 100;
 l = 200;
 h = 30;
 m = 70;
 backwall = {{0, l, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}};
 side1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}, {0, l, h}, {0, l, 0}};
 side2 = {{w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {w, l, 0}};
 floor = {{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {0, l, 0}};
 top = {{0, 0, h}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}};
 front = {{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {0, 0, h}};
 leftRoof = {{0, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {w/2, l, m}, {0, l, h}};
 rightRoof = {{w, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {w/2, l, m}, {w, l, h}};
 fig = Graphics3D[{
   Transparent, Style[Polygon[{backwall, side1, side2, floor, front, leftRoof,rightRoof}],
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Green}}]},
   Boxed -> False,
   RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

But in a second step, I want to fill the building with gas, which is also transparent. Why? Because after filling it with the gas, I will put points inside the building.

For this purpose, I wrote the following code.

```
data = RandomReal[60, {10, 3}];
data1 = RandomReal[60, {10, 3}];
redPoints = Graphics3D[{PointSize -> Large, Style[Point[#], Blue]} & /@ data, 
  Boxed -> False];
bluePoints = Graphics3D[{PointSize -> Large, Style[Point[#], Red]} & /@ data1, 
  Boxed -> False];
Show[{fig, redPoints, bluePoints}]
```

After evaluation of the above code, I am getting an image like this:

[image]

Transparent-building-wise and point-placement-wise this is fine; my problem is filling the building with gas. How can get the gas (light gray color) to fill the inside of the entire building. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So which is it — snow or gas? If it's a colorless gas then problem solved, right? :D (I don't understand your question)

Comment: @ rm -rf ,I want colored gas.I will remove that `snow` word in my question.also feel free ,If you want to edit my question.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating the question with "gas forms"... You probably just want a filled 3D polygon with Opacity.

Comment: @rm-rf you mean,If I write `Opacity[0.3]` instead of `Transparent`in my code.we will get colored `Building` walls still that are also transparent.but I want to make `building` very efficient way,that's why I want fully transparent `Building`walls fill with gas(Light Gray color).

Comment: @PlatoManiac sorry I don't know,meaning of "CFD".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a transparent 3D Rectangle?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/how-can-i-make-a-transparent-3d-rectangle)

Comment: @YvesKlett , in my earlier question I asked for transparent `Rectangle`,not for filling the gas.this question was different.

Comment: @subbu but all you seem to need are semi-transparent polygons, for which this question is entirely sufficient.

Comment: @subbu at least try out Google for "smoke visualization CFD".

Comment: And `Building` is in code blocks because...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RegionPlot3D` creates a surface made of polygons, not a solid volume, so it gives the same result as simply making the original polygons partially transparent.

Adding the roof ends:

```
roofBack = {{w, l, h}, {w/2, l, m}, {0, l, h}};
roofFront = {{w, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {0, 0, h}};
```

This uses just the 9 building polygons rather than the hundreds created by `RegionPlot3D`:

```
building = {backwall, side1, side2, floor, front, 
 leftRoof, rightRoof, roofBack, roofFront};

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5, Gray], Polygon[building]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Notice that the walls are still picking up colour from the lights. As in the original code in the question, you can `Style` the polygons with their own ambient `Lighting` for a completely flat effect:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5, Gray],
  Style[Polygon[building], Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

For a slightly nicer (IMO) effect, you could use `VertexColors` to fade the polygons with increasing z:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
  Style[Polygon[building,
    VertexColors -> Map[0.5 + #[[3]]/80 &, building, {2}]],
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit worried about this idea of filling a building with gas, to be honest. But perhaps some good old-fashioned CO2 would be OK.

```
gas =  Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z}, 
      {x, 10, w - 10, 10}, 
      {y, 10, l - 10, 10}, 
      {z, 10, h - 10, 5}], 2];

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.2, Gray], 
  Polygon[building], 
  White, 
  Opacity[0.1],
  Sphere[#, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]] & /@ gas}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Boxed -> False]
```

You would need to develop a region-function that can fill the space more accurately.

[image: gas]

Comment: Nice gas/giant bed!

Comment: +1 for woolly sheep! lol (warning: processor intensive)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like

```
gas = RegionPlot3D[
  0 < x < 100 && 0 < y < 200 && z > 0 && z < 30 + x/2 && 
  z < 80 - x/2, {x, 0, 250}, {y, 0, 250}, {z, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None]

Show[{fig, redPoints, bluePoints, gas}]
```

[image: gas]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but `RegionPlot` was not fixed exactly inside the `Building`. little bit of gaps are there on the top,sides.I will try that.again thanks for your answer

Comment: subbu, I noticed that as well, that's why I qualified my answer with "something like". Consider my answer as a concept that requires further work.

Comment: added picture - but used PlotPoints to 120 for better fit. Perhaps it's a heavy gas; Wolfium, perhaps - heavier than air? :)

Comment: cormullion, this looks much better, and maybe if you use <= and >= rather than < and >, the gaps might disapear, and if I could just calculate the height of the roof, that might help as well, I'll get right to that...