# How can I fill an entire Building with transparent points?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I am posting the same code found at [an earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20330/how-can-i-fill-a-wire-frame-structure-with-gas-in-a-graphics3d-drawing), although the concept here is totally different.

The following code corresponds to a building-shaped structure.

```
w = 100;
l = 200;
h = 30;
m = 70;
backwall = {{0, l, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}};
side1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}, {0, l, h}, {0, l, 0}};
side2 = {{w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {w, l, 0}};
floor = {{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, l, 0}, {0, l, 0}};
top = {{0, 0, h}, {w, 0, h}, {w, l, h}, {0, l, h}};
front = {{0, 0, 0}, {w, 0, 0}, {w, 0, h}, {0, 0, h}};
leftRoof = {{0, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {w/2, l, m}, {0, l, h}};
rightRoof = {{w, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {w/2, l, m}, {w, l, h}};
roofBack = {{w, l, h}, {w/2, l, m}, {0, l, h}};
roofFront = {{w, 0, h}, {w/2, 0, m}, {0, 0, h}};
building = {backwall, side1, side2, floor, front, leftRoof, rightRoof,roofBack, roofFront};
figure =Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],Style[Polygon[building,VertexColors -> Map[0.5 + #[[3]]/80 &, building, {2}]],Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]}, Boxed -> False,RotationAction -> "Clip"];
data = RandomReal[60, {100, 3}];
data1 = RandomReal[60, {100, 3}];
redPoints = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], PointSize -> Large,Style[Point[#], Blue]} & /@ data, Boxed -> False,RotationAction -> "Clip"];
bluePoints =Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], PointSize -> Large,Style[Point[#], Red]} & /@ data1, Boxed -> False,RotationAction -> "Clip"];
Show[{figure, redPoints, bluePoints}]
```

and upon evaluation it produces:

[image: house with transparent points]

I have 10000 points that need placing, some with coordinates inside the building while the remaining are outside (like the ones circled above).

I have the following two questions:

1. How can I omit the points that are not within the building?
2. How do I fill the entire building with points?

Having tried a few things this morning, I still couldn't get it to work as I want so any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use voxelation ... in order to generate random points or alternative methods as in this paper http://gggj.ujaen.es/vrr/files/P5_final_B&W_3024.pdf you can also check the demo http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoxelDistortion/

Comment: What happened to the gas? Did it all escape? Must be a memory leak in your code...

Comment: @cormullion memory leak in the seance ?

Comment: The 3d lighting looks really good. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

The building is contained in the $w \times l \times m$ cuboid.
You can generate points inside this and then keep only those in the building.

```
side[{P_, Q_, R_, ___}, X_] := Det@Differences[{X, P, Q, R}];
getInsidePolyTest[poly_, knownPointInside_] := 
  Module[{known = Positive[side[#, knownPointInside] & /@ poly]}, 
   Function[pt, (known == Positive[side[#, pt] & /@ poly])]];
inBuildingQ = getInsidePolyTest[building, {1, 1, 1}];

pts = Select[
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, w}, {0, l}, {0, m}}], 1000],
    inBuildingQ];
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[0.2]], Polygon@building, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: building]

Test adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20108/1517) to handle polyhedra with non-consistent orientation of the faces.

Answer (score 3):

If your building is just as simple as the one you posted above, then use `RandomReal` for several times will be simple and fast.

Use these definitions of `data` and `data1` instead:

```
f[x_] := If[x < w/2, (m - h)/w 2 x + h, (m - h)/w 2 (w - x) + h]
getdata := (ll = RandomReal[l, {100}];  
            ww = RandomReal[w, {100}];  
            hh = RandomReal[f@#] & /@ ww;
            Transpose[{ww, ll, hh}])
data = getdata; 
data1 = getdata;
```

Then you get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update:**

If you just need to remove the unwanted points in the data you've already got, you can do the following to your `data` and `data1`:

```
data = RandomReal[60, {100, 3}];
data1 = RandomReal[60, {100, 3}];
f[x_] := If[x < w/2, (m - h)/w 2 x + h, (m - h)/w 2 (w - x) + h]
{data, data1} = Select[#, Last@# < f@First@# &] & /@ {data, data1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ,thanks for your answer,sample example purpose only.I mentioned `RandomReal`,but I have 10000 points.out this points,if any point is out of `Building`(point will checks boundaries of the width,height,length.),just remove that point from the 10000 points list.      but you are changes the point value like,If any point is out of `Building`,you are changed that point into the inside of the `building`.I don't want like that.

Comment: @subbu You mean you've already got 10000 specified points and you want to test if they are inside the building and remove the ones outside?

Comment: exactly it's right,If the point is out of `building`,remove that point from the 10000 points list.

Comment: @subbu See my edit for the answer.

Comment: that one also not working.why because,                   `{data, data1} = Select[#, Last@# < f@First@# &] & /@ {{{-50, 0, 20}}, {{100, 200, 29}}}`.If you try this example,in my point of View the first point will not appear why because,my `Building` is in between "0-100" width,but I mentioned `{-50,0,20}`,so I don't want that point but in your code that point also appeared.                                               why because,you are comparing only the `z-axes`  value only.     I understood,what's the wrong in your code,I will comapare all(x,y,z) axes values.

Comment: @subbu Yeah, that'd be easy to fix, but I think can now go to bed without another edit since you've already understood :D.